# How can enroll student, using unique application number for run Multiple browsers like chrome, firefox in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

**Scenario**: Unique application number(Zee1106) using to enroll students and running testng for Multiple browsers(parallel) like chrome, firefox in selenium webdriver.

In the above scenario, I have run the test suite,first browser(chrome) enrolled successfully and the next browser(firefox) is not enrolled. Because already enrolled alert was coming. In this scenario, How can i enroll students using unique application number for multiple browser in webdriver.

Thanks,
Vairamuthu[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to achieve this. One easiest way is to have the "Application Numbers" stored as a comma separated values in your test data sheet and use each for the respective browsers. Example:

```
  //Assume applicationNo is stored as a comma separated value in test data. Something like this

    String applicationNo="zee1106, zee1107, zee1108"; //please read these data from test data sheet
    String[] unquieAppNo=applicationNo.split(",");

    //get the browserName
    Capabilities caps = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities();
    String browserName = caps.getBrowserName();

    //if the browser name is chrome then use one of the application id and so on for each browser.
    if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){
        driver.findElement(By.id("<employee app number>")).sendKeys(unquieAppNo[0]);
    }else if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
        driver.findElement(By.id("<employee app number>")).sendKeys(unquieAppNo[1]);
    }else{ //any other browser
        driver.findElement(By.id("<employee app number>")).sendKeys(unquieAppNo[2]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell with no code posted at all. Which Language you are working on?Please post the way you instantiate you Webdriver. From your description, I'm guessing that you are using something like this (static):

```
public static WebDriver  driver;
```

Whilst you need a different WebDriver instance everytime:

```
 public WebDriver  driver;
```